# How do I create a "named_scope"-like class method that does nothing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

With named scopes, it was possible to create a scope that took a parameter, but if the parameter was `.blank?` it would do nothing.  How do I achieve the same results with a class method?

Given a model like this

```
class Product
  belongs_to :category

  def self.in_category(id)
    where('"category".id = ?', id) unless id.blank?
  end
end
```

`Product.all.in_category("")` returns nil, but I want it to do the same thing as `Product.all`.

My only thought is to set up `.in_category` as an `if..else..end` with the `else` doing some unnecessary like `where('"category".id = *')` but I don't want to clutter the generated SQL with needless statements.

Comment: Did you try "all" or "scoped" already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide default values to parameters like so:

```
def self.in_category(id = nil) # Allows id to be blank by default
  if id.blank?
    all
  else
    where('"category".id = ?', id) 
  end
end
```

Also, you might consider passing an actual category object to this method, it's rarely wise to work with id's directly:

```
def self.in_category(_category = nil) # Allows id to be blank by default
  if _category.blank?
    all
  else
    where(category: _category) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, that was a simple answer. Trying to follow the advice on moving away from IDs brings up a new question. How do I avoid the ID when I am working with a nested association? Let's say we are tracking items by serial number, so, in addition to the product and category shown above, `SerialNumberedItem belongs_to :product`.  How do I structure the `.where` call in `SerialNumberedItem.in_category`?  `where(category: _category)` builds SQL, looking for a `serial_numbered_items.category` field even with `.join` and/or `delegate`.  Correct SQL would have `category.id` and the needed joins.